# USB хаб странно ведёт себя в Linux

Tags: linux, usb

Товарищи. Купил я себе тут USB хаб **DEXP H7013**. [Ссылка на сам хаб](https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/591ada9035851b80/usb-razvetvitel-dexp-h7013/), если кому интересно.
Сам работаю на Linux.

В lsusb он виден так:

```bash
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 019: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub
Bus 008 Device 018: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub
```

Да. Сразу как три устройства (хаб пустой). И Bluetooth вставленный в него виден в lsusb:

```bash
Bus 008 Device 020: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB Keykoard
```

Правда почему-то, как клавиатура и не работает. Хотя в обычном порту Bluetooth виден нормально и работает:

```bash
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
```

То же с любыми другими устройствами. Будучи вставленными в этот USB хаб они видны в lsusb, но так, как в других USB портах и, естественно, что из-за этого они все не пашут, потому как ловят не свои драйвера.

Сдать я его не могу, потому как он себя так ведёт только у меня на Linux. В магазине на Windows он работает как нужно.